# ValueError: could not convert string to float despite value already being an int not a string

Tags: python, tkinter

I've set up a GUI with entry widgets.

```
def gui_function():
value = v.get()
if value == 2:
    print 'Converting from decimal to binary...'
    foundvalu = float(dec_entry_a.get())

    new_num_input = int(foundvalu)

    result = Decimal_to_Binary.convert2(new_num_input)

    bin_out_b.config(state=NORMAL)
    bin_out_b.delete(0, END)
    bin_out_b.insert(0, result)"
```

When I run the GUI and enter 37 into the entry widget I receive the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Converting from decimal to binary...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1537, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/DeclanTK/Documents/School/Drexel/Winter Term Sophomore/ECEC 301 (Advanced Programming)/Project/Egg Project/Binary Converter egg/BtoDConverter-0.1/My_Files/Number_Converter_GUI.py", line 38, in gui_function
    foundvalu = float(dec_entry_a.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I can offer more code but I simply can't see why it won't accept 37 and convert it to a float.

Comment: Check if the type of `dec_entry_a.get()` is a `class 'str'` by `type(dec_entry_a.get())`.

Comment: Try printing the string: `print(dec_entry_a.get())`  You know that `float('37')` works, so you must not be getting "37".  Once you find out what you've got, it will be easier to figure out where it came from.

Comment: Right now nothing happens unless value ==2, everything is in the same indent level.

Comment: i added a line that prints type(dec_entry_a.get()), and it tells me its a string, even though I'm typing in 37. I'm sorry this may sound foolish im just a novice at this whole coding thing haha

Comment: What is `v`? An entry widget? `StringVar`? `IntVar`?